# Storing objects in arrays and then accessing them

Tags: c#, arrays, string, oop, object

I wrote the following code as a quick and dirty POC, and everything works up until I try and access the objects in the array I created.

As you can see in the code below I am trying to access the object in the array with the following line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine("AWS Account Id = {0]", array1[1].AccountId);
```

The Entire code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class AWSAccount
    {
        public string AccountId { get; set; }
        public string[] Instances { get; set; }
        public AWSAccount(string accountId, string[] instances)
        {
            AccountId = accountId;
            Instances = instances;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] instances1 = {"i-xxxxx01", "i-xxxxx02"};
            AWSAccount account1 = new AWSAccount("53853288254", instances1);
            Console.WriteLine("AWS Account Id = {0} Instances = {1} {2}", account1.AccountId, account1.Instances[0], account1.Instances[1]);

            string[] instances2 = { "i-zzzzz01", "i-zzzzz02" };
            AWSAccount account2 = new AWSAccount("74378834238", instances2);
            Console.WriteLine("AWS Account Id = {0} Instances = {1} {2}", account2.AccountId, account2.Instances[0], account2.Instances[1]);


            object[] array1 = new object[2];
            array1[0] = account1;
            array1[1] = account2;

            Console.WriteLine("AWS Account Id = {0}", array1[0].AccountId);
            Console.WriteLine("AWS Account Id = {0}", array1[1].AccountId);

            // Keep the console open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

The intellisense doesnt pickup the .AccountId, and it highlights it with the below error.

```
Error   1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'AccountId' and no extension method 'AccountId' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Users\jploof\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs    37  65  ConsoleApplication1
```

Comment: What is the problem/error?

Comment: and you problem is? what are you asking?

Comment: Your `Console.WriteLine` methods contain `{0]`.  Match up your braces.

Comment: OP edited to include problem and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your Main() procedure using `AWSAccount[] array1 = new AWSAccount[2]` as shown below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string[] instances1 = { "i-xxxxx01", "i-xxxxx02" };
    AWSAccount account1 = new AWSAccount("53853288254", instances1);
    Console.WriteLine("AWS Account Id = {0} Instances = {1} {2}", account1.AccountId, account1.Instances[0], account1.Instances[1]);

    string[] instances2 = { "i-zzzzz01", "i-zzzzz02" };
    AWSAccount account2 = new AWSAccount("74378834238", instances2);

    Console.WriteLine("AWS Account Id = {0} Instances = {1} {2}", account2.AccountId, account2.Instances[0], account2.Instances[1]);

    AWSAccount[] array1 = new AWSAccount[2];
    array1[0] = account1;
    array1[1] = account2;

    Console.WriteLine("AWS Account Id = {0}", array1[0].AccountId);
    Console.WriteLine("AWS Account Id = {0}", array1[1].AccountId);

    // Keep the console open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Note** the syntax error in your original post: `"AWS Account Id = {0]"`

Hope this may help.

Comment: I corrected the syntax and made the other changes, but now it is complaining about the "array1[0].AccountId" formatting.. FormatException was unhandled. {"Input string was not in a correct format."}... I tried adding ToString(), and no bueno.

Comment: Just Copy-Paste the entire code snippet from my answer; it works just fine (tested in real app). Best regards,

Comment: Nice! That worked! I will have to use beyond compare against what you had and what I had and figure out where I messed up! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad it works for you. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Change your object[]  to AWSAccount[] that should sort you out.

Comment: This seems to be getting me closer, but now its complaing about the "array1[0].AccountId" formatting.. FormatException was unhandled. {"Input string was not in a correct format."}... I tried adding ToString(), and no bueno.